# What is the correct way to recover from ZFS errors after a power failure?

Tags: linux, zfs

A couple times I have had sudden power loss which made a ZFS pool unusable until after a full system reboot. I plan to get a UPS to avoid future issues, but it seems there should be a way to correct such a simple problem without a full system shutdown.

Reproducing the issue is very easy: My ZFS pool runs off two hard drives which are connected via USB. This is the status while the pool is running correctly:

```
$ sudo zpool status
pool: tank
state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 1h36m with 0 errors on Sun Dec 11 02:00:22 2016
config:

NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
tank                                                ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
    usb-ST4000DM_000-1F2168_000000000000-0:0-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
    usb-ST3000DM_001-1E6166_000000000000-0:1-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

If I switch off the power to the USB drives without stopping ZFS first, and then turn on the power again after a few seconds the following issues occur:
If I try to LS inside the ZFS mount point, it will hang indefinitely, requiring me to close the terminal. (The ls process will remain as a zombie). Any computers connected to the nfs server via samba will likewise hang if they try to access the shared directory.

The status will now look like:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to IO failures.
action: Make sure the affected devices are connected, then run 'zpool clear'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-HC
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 1h36m with 0 errors on Sun Dec 11 02:00:22 2016
config:

NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
tank                                                UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
  mirror-0                                          UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
    usb-ST4000DM_000-1F2168_000000000000-0:0-part1  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
    usb-ST3000DM_001-1E6166_000000000000-0:1-part1  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
```

despite the fact that the USB drives have been turned on again.

I've tried the following commands to fix the issue.

```
$ sudo zpool clear tank
cannot clear errors for tank: I/O error

$ sudo zfs unmount tank
cannot open 'tank': pool I/O is currently suspended

# Note: Because other computers were trying to access the zfs share via     samba, there are zombie processes, which is why an export won't work.

$ sudo zpool export tank
umount: /tank: target is busy
    (In some cases useful info about processes that
     use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
cannot unmount '/tank': umount failed

$ sudo zpool export -f tank
umount: /tank: target is busy
    (In some cases useful info about processes that
     use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
cannot unmount '/tank': umount failed

# Tried this just for kicks, and got the expected result.
$ sudo zpool import -nfF tank
cannot import 'tank': a pool with that name already exists
use the form 'zpool import <pool | id> <newpool>' to give it a new name
```

I spent a few hours reading similar posts from people, but none of them seem to 
address this exact issue. If I reboot the computer running ZFS all errors
will disappear, dead processes are cleared up, and everything returns to normal.

But there must be a cleaner way to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I should probably clarify. The server which the drives are attached to is a repurposed laptop, so it has an internal power supply. So under normal operation if there is a power outage, it is possible for the USB drives to lose power and later come up again without the server/laptop ever going through a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your scenario at the moment, but the first thing I would try after such a failure is to `zpool reopen` the pool, and possibly `zpool online` the device(s) if needed. For example, when you have

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to IO failures.
action: Make sure the affected devices are connected, then run 'zpool clear'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-HC
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 1h36m with 0 errors on Sun Dec 11 02:00:22 2016
config:

NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
tank                                                UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
  mirror-0                                          UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
    usb-ST4000DM_000-1F2168_000000000000-0:0-part1  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
    usb-ST3000DM_001-1E6166_000000000000-0:1-part1  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
```

you could try to

```
$ sudo zpool reopen tank
```

and if that doesn't clear things up completely also

```
$ sudo zpool online tank 'usb-ST4000DM_000-1F2168_000000000000-0:0-part1'
$ sudo zpool online tank 'usb-ST3000DM_001-1E6166_000000000000-0:1-part1'
```

It's perfectly possible that merely `zpool reopen $POOL` will get the pool working again, as it instructs ZFS to reopen all devices associated with the pool. (The man page describes it tersely as *Reopen all the vdevs associated with the pool.* I don't know if it will trigger a vdev scan or if it will simply attempt to reopen under the already known names.) As long as the devices are still found under the same names, that *should* be enough, and it *might* be enough if the devices are known by alternative names (if a vdev scan is performed).

You may still need to `zpool clear` any I/O errors afterwards, but that depends on whether ZFS had time to log them. If both drives died, it's likely ZFS didn't have time to log the errors to the drives, so `zpool clear` should not be needed.

As an aside, you can also check out the `failmode` property of the pool (`zpool get failmode tank`). It sounds like your pool currently has `failmode=wait` but for your use case, `failmode=continue` may be more appropriate. See `man 8 zpool` for a description of the various values for the `failmode` property.

Comment: Reopen leads to: 'cannot reopen 'tank': pool I/O is currently suspended', online leads to 'cannot online usb-ST4000DM_000-1F2168_000000000000-0:0-part1: pool I/O is currently suspended', and clear leads to 'cannot clear errors for tank: I/O error'. I know the devices are actually connected because one of them has a second partition which I can read and write from. Setting failmode does not help, as writes will still block. Thanks however.

Comment: @klfwip You would of course set failmode when the pool is working normally.

Comment: Well, I can turn 'continue' on, and it would allow listing and reading files. But if my understanding of the ZFS docs is correct, the mode only means that reads are allowed, but writes fail with an EIO error. So I'd still need to reboot the server before the share is completely usable again.